# postfix unused parameter error

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

For a long time I have been trying to get postfix to work on my server, I gave up a while back but now I have no choice but to get it working.

after configuring the main.cf file and restarting postfix there seems to be a number of errors which I have no idea how to fix even after googling for solutions.

**Errors**

```
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_client_restriction=permit_mynetworks,reject_unknown_client,permit
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: body_check=regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smptd_sasl_type=dovecot
/usr/sbin/postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smptd_sasl_path=private/auth
```

**main.cf**

```
command_directory = /usr/sbin

daemon_directory = /usr/lib/postfix

data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix

myhostname = mail.xxxxxxbooks.com

mydomain = xxxxxxbooks.com

myorigin = $mydomain

inet_interfaces = all

mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain

local_recipient_maps = unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps

unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, 78.129.200.10

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

home_mailbox = Maildir/

header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks

body_check = regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP

debugger_command =
     PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
     ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/postfix

newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases

mailq_path =  /usr/bin/mailq

setgid_group = postdrop

message_size_limit = 10485760


smptd_sasl_type = dovecot
smptd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname

smtpd_client_restriction = permit_mynetworks,reject_unknown_client,permit 
#smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_auth_destination,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject 
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
```

**Edit**

I have an Ubuntu 12.04.1 server which runs apache.

If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: What OS, version and postfix version are you using?

Comment: Sorry I forgot the add that in, i'll edit the question

Comment: @NickW Ubuntu 12.04.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've misspelled the parameters.

It's `smtpd_client_restrictions` <-- note the s

`body_checks`

`smtpd_sasl_path` not smptd

the same thing for `smtpd_sasl_type`

Comment: OK, the only warning I have left is 
`postconf: warning: /etc/postfix/main.cf: unused parameter: smtpd_client_restriction=permit_mynetworks,reject_unknown_client,permit`

Should I remove this line?

Comment: no, add an s to the end of restriction.. after all it's not just one restriction, it's multiple :)

Comment: You're welcome, best of luck!