# Applying filter on mail from specific subnet in postfix

Tags: postfix, email-server, filter

I'm trying to get the following to work:

We have a postfix relay on the edge of our network, accepting all mail from our internal LAN & DMZ. What we are trying to get to work is limiting the maildomains a specific subnet (test & dev) can send mail to. Basically, this:

```
production-subnet -> relay:25 -> outbound mail all domains        = OK
test-subnet       -> relay:25 -> outbound mail all domains        = NOK
test-subnet       -> relay:25 -> outbound mail to allowed domain  = OK
```

I've tried check_send_access maps, but they can only allow or disallow mail from a sender, and can't filter based on recipient domain. In an ideal world where developers check their output, this wouldn't be necessary at all, but we've had a few occasions where dev was copied from production and suddenly people got rogue-mailed by the dev-environment and we want to stop that from happening again whilst still retaining the ability to be able to send mail to our own domain (for cronmail, et al)

I have toyed with the idea of setting up a second relay specific for this purpose, but due to a large (mostly unmanaged by ansible) environment, that would be significantly more work to get this to work, which is why I would prefer to do it on the existing relay on the standard smtp port.

Comment: Similiar case with yours: [postfix relay based on origin](http://serverfault.com/a/653759/218590). You can just replace `/etc/postfix/devbox` with your whitelisted domain :)

Comment: smtpd_restriction_classes were exactly what I was looking for, this fits my problem perfectly! :D Thanks a lot!